# log4j not writing logs to a file

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Log4j is not writing the log files to a file but writing to console. I searched through a lot of resources (i think this question already exists) for it but was unable to find a solution.

**Log4j version 1.2.17**

Below is my log4j configuration:

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout , File
>
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t
>   %c{20}:%L - %m%n
>
> log4j.category.org.springframework=ERROR
>   log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=ERROR
>   log4j.category.com.mypackage=INFO
>   log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR
>   log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
>   log4j.logger.org.hibernate.persister.entity=ERROR
>
> log4j.appender.File = org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.File.File=/tmp/mylog.log
>   log4j.appender.File.ImmediateFlush=true
>   log4j.appender.File.threshold=INFO log4j.appender.File.Append=true
>   log4j.appender.File.MaxFileSize=10MB
>   log4j.appender.File.MaxBackupIndex=20
>   log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t
>   %c{2}:%L - %m%n log4j.appender.File.rollingPolicy =
>   org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
>   log4j.appender.File.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern
>   =/tmp/mylog%d.log 
>   log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t
>   %c{2}:%L - %m%n

I have made sure I have permissions to the directory where i am trying to write to. 
Can some one please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Please make the below mentioned changes to your config file.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/mylog.log
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n 
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/tmp/mylog%d.log 
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t  %c{2}:%L - %m%n
```

Hope this works fine.

Comment: Did you find this helpful?